# Using KIF to tap on status bar or doing it programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, functional-testing, kif-framework, kif

I have looked quite a bit, but I'm unable to find a way to use KIF to tap on the status bar area of the simulator.  I'd like to do this to test for scrolling to the top of a table view by tapping there.

Two methods I've tried:

```
CGFloat middleOfScreen = floorf([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.f);
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow tapAtPoint:CGPointMake(middleOfScreen, 0.f)];
```

and

```
[self tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f)];
```

Is this possible using KIF?  If not, is this even possible using UITouch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian Nickel was nice enough to add this in the latest master branch here: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/commit/534ec0594d993b868cf9a04495254b30926189cd

The syntax will be:

```
[tester tapStatusBar];
```